# DIfferences between Jenkins projects

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

What is the difference between a these Jenkins project types:

```
Pipeline
Multi Branch Pipeline
Github Organization
```

I am using a Jenkinsfile.

I think for Pipeline, it just supports one Branch, where as Multi Branch supports any branch. Github Organization not sure. I want to update Pull Request from Github with Jenkins build statuses.

Answer (score 2):

- Pipeline job is basically asking Jenkins to run a pipeline written in Groovy. You either "paste" this Groovy code into a text field in Jenkins, or tell Jenkins "the Groovy code is somewhere there in the SCM". Your job is "freestyle" and so can do  anything — make cleanups, send emails, or download cat pictures, and, of course, it can roll the build-test-deploy cycle.

  Note that your job may, for example, ask for branch name, and build several branches provided with their names. (Theoretically, it can also ask for repo URL, and build several repos.)
- Multibranch job basically tells Jenkins that there's a repo that has several branches (some of them PRs). This is  better fit for build-test-deploy cycle. In this type, each branch has its own Jenkinsfile (it was created when the branch was forked from `master` or whatever), and each branch is built according to its own Jenkinsfile.

  This is what most people want, and here's why: Let's assume the "usual" project build delivers three deliverables (binaries, tars, jars or whatever), and I have a PR that adds a fourth one. Where would I put the instructions on how to build this fourth thing? In Multibranch, I add the instructions to my branch's Jenkinsfile. My branch produces four deliverables, the other branches three. When my branch is merged, master branch gets to four, etc.

  (In a single pipeline, I'd need to modify my single project-wide Jenkinsfile with if-else instructions, and this could quickly get out of hand.)
- Github Organization is very similar, but has closer integration with GitHub, so is only relevant if this is what you work with (not relevant for e.g. BitBucket).

Comment: do you know how to connect my Github repo with a Github Organization Project?

Comment: Did you try New item -> GitHub Organization -> provide URL?

Answer (score 1):

- In a [pipeline job](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/), you specify in which branch your Jenkinsfile is.
- But in a Multibranch Pipeline, each branch can have its own Jenkinsfile.
- The [GitHub Organization folder](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-organization-folder-plugin) is used to scan a GitHub Organization or Bitbucket Team to discover an organization’s repositories, automatically creating managed Multibranch Pipeline jobs for them.

> update Pull Request from Github with Jenkins build statuses

You can follow "[How to update Jenkins build status in GitHub pull requests [Step-by-Step Tutorial]](https://applitools.com/blog/how-to-update-jenkins-build-status-in-github-pull-requests-step-by-step-tutorial)", which uses a WebHook.

Or you can use the [GitHub PR Builder Plugin](https://medium.com/@mreigen/integrate-jenkins-builds-into-github-pull-requests-33bc053d6210)

Comment: I was thinking of using Github PR Builder but it says its deprecated

Comment: @henhen Yes, https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-branch-source/ is probably the more recent plugin.

Comment: Yes, that is the one I am trying to use, but they recommend using the Github Org Folder type for the Jenkins project. But I'm reading a lot of Docs that just use Multi Branch Pipeline or just Pipeline. Not sure which one to use

Comment: @henhen Github Org Folder is to create multi branch automatically, so in your case, multi branch is a good option.

Comment: I have not tested them, but yes, they should both work.